# inputText props is not working in react-native

Tags: react-native

i have created two component apptextinput and screen login.in apptextinput  I make it reusable component here is my code

```
export default function AppTextInput({ icon, ...otherProps }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {icon && (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name={icon}
          size={30}
          color={colors.red}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
      )}
      <TextInput style={defaultStyles.text} {...otherProps} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and the second component I passed above reusable component which contain icon and ...other props but only icon is showing in input other prop like autocapitalize ,onchangetext placeholder ,keyboadrtype and other props are not working only icon render  here is my code
[image]

```
export default function ScreenLogin() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  return (
    <ExpoScreen>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo.png")} />
      <AppTextInput
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        icon="email"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        placeholder="Email"
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
      />
      <AppTextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        icon="lock"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        placeholder="Password"
        textContentType="password"
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <AppButton title="login" onPress={() => console.log(email, password)} />
    </ExpoScreen>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the current value also in TextInput

```
export default function ScreenLogin() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  return (
    <ExpoScreen>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo.png")} />
      <AppTextInput
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        icon="email"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        placeholder="Email"
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        value={email}   // HERE IS THE CHANGE
      />
      <AppTextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        icon="lock"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        placeholder="Password"
        textContentType="password"
        secureTextEntry
        value={password}   // HERE IS THE CHANGE
      />
      <AppButton title="login" onPress={() => console.log(email, password)} />
    </ExpoScreen>
  );
}
```

You can try changing this as well

```
export default function AppTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {props.icon && (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name={props.icon}
          size={30}
          color={colors.red}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
      )}
      <TextInput style={defaultStyles.text} {...props} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have editied AppTextInput as well. Please try changing that as well

Comment: <AppTextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        icon="lock"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        placeholder="Password"
        textContentType="password"
        secureTextEntry
        value={password}
      />

Comment: changed but no luck

Comment: check i have changed

Comment: I have edited my answer and changed the function AppTextInput props destructuring. Did you try that?